# Dependence of $nq-p^2$ on $a$ if $p=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(a+i)$, $q=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(a+i)^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

> If $p$ and $q$ are the sum and the sum of squares of $n$ successive integers beginning with '$a$' then $nq-p^2$ is

$$
p=\frac{n}{2}[2a+n-1]=na+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\\
q=a^2+(a+1)^2+(a+2)^2+...+(a+n-1)^2\\
=na^2+2a[1+2+...+(n-1)]+1^2+2^2+...+(n-1)^2\\
=na^2+2a\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}\\
=na^2+an(n-1)+\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}
$$
$$
nq-p^2=n^2a^2+an^2(n-1)+\frac{n^2(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}-n^2a^2-\frac{n^2(n-1)^2}{4}-an^2(n-1)\\
=\frac{n^2(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}-\frac{n^2(n-1)^2}{4} \implies \text{ Independent of } a
$$

But my reference says $nq-p^2$ is dependent on $a$, what is going wrong here ?

Comment: You are correct, the expression is always $\frac {n^4-n^2}{12}$, independent of $a$.

Comment: This is interesting, I wonder, is there an easier way (maybe combinatoric?) to see that this in fact is independent of $a$?